# Setting server time correctly - Moqui vs. server

Tags: moqui

can I adjust time settings in the application so that correct times (in terms of my TZ) are saved? Or do I have to adjust the server time?

Answer (score 1):

Time zones are handled in Moqui in a standard way. The point in time in Timestamp objects has no time zone (milliseconds since epoch) so the time zone only comes into play when converting it to another form, such as parsing a String from user or other input or printing a String... or in some cases saving to and loading from a database.

Some databases use a no timezone internal representation, for others ALL Timestamp, Date, Time objects are saved and loaded using the database time zone. The database time zone is set using the entity-facade.@database-time-zone attribute in the Moqui Conf XML file, or if not set defaults to the server's time zone (ie Java's default time zone).